# Try ... catch ... finally return value

Tags: scala

I found that it's a shame that I can't return a return value from a such simple construction as `try ... catch ... finally`

```
 def foo: String = {
    val in = new BufferedReader(.....)
    try {
      // val in = new BufferedReader(.....) -- doesn't matter
      in.readLine
    }
    catch {
      case e: IOException => e.printStackTrace()
    }
    finally {
      in.close()
    }
  }
```

This code doesn't compile. Is there any way to make compile **expect** using any libraries, high-level constructions, etc? I want to do that only by using the capacity of pure Scala as a programming language.

Comment: Suggestion: in the future, post the error so others don't have to actually try to run your code.

Comment: @pedrofurla, are you sure they had to run this code?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In a scala try-catch-finally block, the `finally` block is evaluated *only* for side effects; the value of the block as a whole is the value of the last expression in the `try` (if no exception was thrown) or `catch` (if one was).

If you look at the output from the compiler, you'll note that it's complaining about the contents of the `catch` block, not the `finally`:

```
$ scala test.scala
/tmp/test.scala:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String
    case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
```

This is because `Exception.printStackTrace()` returns `Unit`, so the return type of the function would have to be `String` if the `try` succeeded and `Unit` otherwise.

You can address this by having the `catch` block evaluate to a String as well:

```
catch {
  case e: IOException => {
    e.printStackTrace()
    e.toString()
  }
}
```

Of course, this means there has to be some useful string value you can return even when an error occurs (perhaps `""`?); a more idiomatic approach might be to return an `Option[String]`, with the `try` block returning `Some(in.readLine)` and the `catch` block returning `None`. In either case, though, the value of both the `try` and `catch` blocks must match the function signature. The `finally` block's type is irrelevant.

For reference, here's a version that passes type checking and works:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.IOException

def foo: String = {
  val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
  try {
    in.readLine
  }
  catch {
    case e: IOException => { e.printStackTrace(); e.toString() }
  }
  finally {
    in.close()
  }
}

System.out.println("Return value: " + foo)
```

`in.close()` returns Unit, but that's ok because the value of the `finally` block is ignored. The `try` and `catch` blocks both return String.

Comment: what about in.close() in finally block?

Comment: `in.close()` will be executed, but its return value will be ignored, whether an exception is thrown or not - only the `try` and `catch` blocks affect the return value of the try-catch-finally.

Comment: I think it's better to use Option[String] for try...catch, isn't it?

Comment: @MariusKavansky It is, and I mentioned that in my answer, but I wanted to focus on explaining the behaviour of the try-catch and not get sidetracked completely rewriting the code.

Comment: Way more idiomatic in this case is to use a `Try[String]` as a return value. Or even drop the `try ... catch` in favor of `Try(in.readLine)`.

Comment: Can the return type of the catch block be `Nothing`, if we terminate?

Answer (score 14):

I think it would help to start with the Java conception of an exception. A Java method is basically a contract to do something (return a value or cause a side effect) if it is called. The method makes certain assumptions (for example, that the operating system will cooperate with a request to read a file). Sometimes, if these conditions are not met, it will return a null value, and sometimes it will stop execution completely and "throw an exception".

This can be a problem, because the contract of a Java method is not always clear. A Java method that declares a return type of String really has three outcomes: a String value, null, or an exception. One problem with exceptions is that they halt execution of the code, possibly masking other problems further down in the method or possibly failing to close resources that were opened (which is the reason for `try, catch, finally`)

Scala seeks clarity regarding the return type. One way to do this would be to collect all the exceptions that occur in the method and then pass that list of exceptions as a return value. But then, we need to have a return type that says "We're going to return something, or we might return nothing" ([scala.Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html)), or perhaps, "We're going to return Either the expected answer or we'll return information about why the expected answer is not being returned" ([scala.util.Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html)), or perhaps, "We're going to Try to do a risky operation, which might result in Success or Failure." ([scala.util.Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html))

Scala deals with the possibility of a null value with Option. Option is class that has two subclasses: `None` and `Some`, which is a container that holds exactly one element. For example:

```
val contacts = Map("mark" -> 1235551212, "john" -> 2345551212, "william" -> 3455551212)
val phoneOfJohn: Option[Int] = contacts.get("john")
val phoneOfAlex: Option[Int] = contacts.get("alex")

phoneOfJohn match {
  case Some(number) => callPhone(number) 
  case None         => Logger.debug("unable to call John, can't find him in contacts")
}

phoneOfAlex match {
  case Some(number) => callPhone(number) 
  case None         => Logger.debug("unable to call Alex, can't find him in contacts")
}
```

This codes make a phone call to John, and it will log the fact that it was unable call Alex because it couldn't find his phone number in the phone book. But an `Option` doesn't provide information about why no value was returned. If we want to collect those reasons, we can use an `Either`. The `Either` has two subclasses: A `Left` could store all of the exceptions that were collected in the process of doing the "risky operation" while a `Right` would be similar to a `Some` and contain the expected value.

Doing a [fold](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html#fold[C](fa:A=%3EC,fb:B=%3EC):C) operation on an Either to convert it to a Left or a Right is somewhat counter-intuitive, and thus we come to scala.util.Try.

[@marius](https://twitter.com/marius), a scala developer at Twitter, wrote a very good [post](http://aboutwhichmorelater.tumblr.com/post/30409572482/scala-util-try) about the rationale for adopting [scala.util.Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html). I think this is what you're looking for.

The essence of scala.util.Try is that a risky action can result in `Success` or `Failure`. Before scala.util.Try, developers would use an Option or Either. Here's what it would look like if you did a buffered reader from a file:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Failure, Success}

def foo(fileName: String): Try[String] = Try {
  scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName).bufferedReader().readLine()
}

def bar(file: String): Unit = foo(file) match {
  case Success(answer) => Logger.info(s"$file says the answer is $answer")
  case Failure(e) => Logger.error(s"couldn't get answer, errors: ${e.getStackTrace}")
}

bar("answer.txt") \\ will log the answer or a stack trace
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because in Scala unlike Java, try-catch are expressions. In your code, try block returns a `String` and your catch block return type is `Unit` (as you are just printing and returning nothing).

The type-inference hence takes the return type `T` such that `T >: Unit` and `T >: String`. Hence `T` is of type `Any`. And because you have declared foo as `def foo: String`. The compiler throws an error as it was expecting String but found Any.

What you can do is to return a default value under you catch block:

```
try{
  in.readLine
}
catch {
  case e: IOException => {
             e.printStackTrace()
             "error string"
         }
}
 finally{
     in.close
 }
```

Comment: where is finally block?

Comment: `finally` block is not considered as an expression so your code will suffice. I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

This method returns a `Unit`; you have to return something in the catch block; or I'd rather suggest to change the return type to e.g. `Option`; or use `Try` class.

What is obvious - you don't always have a string in this situation. In Java people tend to ignore the realities, but this is Scala, one can do better.