# Scala behavior differs from Java only because Java try finally does not result in value

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and while going through Programming in Scala by Martin Odersky i confronted this statement - Scala behavior differs from Java only because Java try finally does not result in value.
Can someone explain this with Example

Comment: The first answer explains it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685573/try-catch-finally-return-value

Answer (score 1):

In scala, everything is an expression, which implies that it returns a value. `1+1` expresses the value `2`. In java, try..catches essentially return void. You can't set a variable with void since that doesn't mean anything. Its an error for the java compiler.

This is one of those syntax sugar things that scala brought to the table.

```
val foo: String = if (bar == true) { "It was true" }
                  else { "It is false" }
```

The above code would set the value of foo depending on the result of the if condition

For try catches

```
val foo: String = try { readFirstLineFromFile() }
                  catch { "Cannot find file" }
                  finally { makeSureFileIsClosed() }
```

The above block will also set the value of foo.